# Adding popup menu items to JChart2D's ChartPanel

Tags: java, swing, charts, jpopupmenu

Is it possible to add menu items to JChart2D's ChartPanel pop up menu, considering the class doesn't actually save the JPopupMenu created by the LayoutFactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, not sure if it's the best:

```
public class MyChartpanel extends ChartPanel {
  private JPopupMenu popup;
  public MyChartpanel(Chart2D chart) {
    super(chart);
    MouseListener[] listeners = chart.getMouseListeners();

    for (MouseListener listener : listeners) {
      if (listener instanceof PopupListener) {
        PopupListener popupListener = (PopupListener) listener;
        popup = popupListener.getPopup();
        popup.add(new MyMenuItem());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I never used I think that JChart2D's ChartPanel, but [JChart2D Features](http://jchart2d.sourceforge.net/feature.shtml) told something about [JPopupMenu](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) , [setComponentPopupMenu](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu%28javax.swing.JPopupMenu%29), [How to Use the System Tray](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html), [How to Use Separators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/separator.html) examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Popup-menu.htm) and about [PopupMenuListener](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/0640__PopupMenuListener.htm)

Comment: Yes, it uses JPopupMenu implementation, and a PopupMenuListener called PopupListener, I've been playing around with these for a few days now unsuccessfully. I think I'm just overlooking something easy.